# How to print the output by passing the following matrix?

Tags: python

Want to pass the matrix to the following code `matrix = [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]` and print the output (to debug and understand well)  just want to know where to pass and print the matrix

```
class Solution(object):
def setZeroes(self, matrix):

    col0 = False
    R = len(matrix)
    C = len(matrix[0])
    for i in range(R):

        if matrix[i][0] == 0:
            col0 = True
        for j in range(1, C):
            # If an element is zero, we set the first element of the corresponding row and column to 0
            if matrix[i][j] == 0:
                matrix[0][j] = 0
                matrix[i][0] = 0

    # Iterate over the array once again and using the first row and first column, update the elements.
    for i in range(1, R):
        for j in range(1, C):
            if not matrix[i][0] or not matrix[0][j]:
                matrix[i][j] = 0

    # See if the first row needs to be set to zero as well
    if matrix[0][0] == 0:
        for j in range(C):
            matrix[0][j] = 0

    # See if the first column needs to be set to zero as well
    if col0:
        for i in range(R):
            matrix[i][0] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setZeroes` from an instance of `Solution` such as

```
sol = Solution()
sol.setZeroes([[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]])
```

then you can just `print(matrix)` within `setZeroes` at any point that you are interested. Or better yet this is a good time to become familiar with [an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) where you can set breakpoints and view the values of local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `setZeroes` requires the `self` instance and the matrix argument, you can call it by firstly creating an instance of `Solution` and then calling its method passing your `matrix`:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]
Solution().setZeroes(matrix)
print(martix)
```

Note that `setZeroes` modifies the `matrix` itself "inplace" (it is a list of lists: it can be done). Therefore, you just need to look at values in `matrix` to see the effect.

Another approach could be to copy the `matrix` within your `setZeroes` method and `return` your result.